# How define sieve_global_dir in dovecot's sieve-test

Tags: dovecot, sieve

I created a few sieve (dovecot implementation) filter scripts and want to test them using sieve-test.

All scripts which are using global includes are failing with the following message

```
Error: sieve: include: sieve_global_dir not set for :global script include (wanted script 'bugzilla.sieve')
```

The sieve_global_dir is set in dovecot.conf and the include works when started by `deliver`.

How to define sieve_global_dir that it is read by `sieve-test` and `sievec`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to parts of the wiki and reading a little source code from dovecot.org:

http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Sieve/Dovecot

...you should be able to do something like:

```
export SIEVE_DIR=/some/path
export SIEVE_GLOBAL_DIR=/some/other/path
sievec -d -P /some/file.sieve
```

The source is complicated, but if I read the Pigeonhole sieve sources correctly the lib-sieve/plugins/environment/ code will read in anything you define, and sievec has checks for setting these two values out of the environment when run. I can't confirm this though as I don't have it installed to test, YMMV.

Comment: SIEVE_GLOBAL_DIR is exactly what I needed. And I can confirm, it is as you said ;) Thanks a lot

Comment: sweet, my first bounty! I feel so *special*. :)

Comment: well, I got half of it - why didn't you award the whole thing to me? sad panda face. :(

Comment: I marked it as answer. I'm sorry, I did not realize that I need to mark it somewhere else too, it was my first bounty :( What should I have done to mark your post?

Comment: aha! no worries... ok, looked it up and it appears there's a Bounty link to click to "award" it as well, in addition to the normal question stuff. http://serverfault.com/faq#bounty oh well, we'll get 'er next time!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but i don't think the solution is right.

In dovecot 2.x.x doing

`export SIEVE_GLOBAL_DIR=/some/other/path`

won't work.

i have added the following line to the dovecot.conf file (inside the `plugin` section):

```
sieve_global_dir=/etc/dovecot/sieve/
```

And every think works!

Obviously that path must contain a `sieve.global` file.

Thank you.